# Dune sand tent underground - why wouldn't digging and just being in a tent attract a worm?

Tags: dune, sandworm

Seems like being inside a sand tent down inside a dune would act like a vibration amplifying chamber -- even the vibration of simply breathing, snoring. etc - much less any movements would be amplified nto the compacted drum-like sand  (from the sand compaction tool) such that it would essentially be a horn call to a sandworm??

Random movements seemingly could only take you so far.

Comment: Two things: First, a tent is buried in part by dune-making processes of the wind. The second thing is that what digging there *is* is brief, and it is not like every single moment of vibration at the surface results in a worm attack.

Comment: If you dig without rhythm, you won't attract the worm

Answer (score 9):

Building a stilltent on open sand does sound dangerous. It's worth noting that the tents we see being used in *Dune* are mainly sited on rocky outcrops, presumably so that the Worms will avoid them.

> Paul stared out the transparent end of the stilltent at **the
> moonshadowed rocks that ringed this place** where Idaho had hidden them.

and

> Night still covered **the stilltent within its rock-enclosed hideaway**.
> His mother’s grief could still be heard.

and

> “I’ll put up the tent,” he said. “Better slip off that robe and shake it out.” He turned away, taking the pack.
> Jessica nodded, suddenly too tired to answer.
> **“There’s anchor holes in the rock,” Paul said. “Someone’s tented here before.”**

Where tents are used on the open erg, it's on soft sand sheltered by surrounding dunes, where presumably their sounds will be muffled.

> The reassurance gave him a new hold on his world. Bits of solid
> reality began to dip through the dream state into his awareness. He
> knew suddenly that he was in a hiereg, a desert camp. Chani had
> planted their stilltent on flour-sand for its softness.

Comment: Notably, the tent that paul and his mother use (which gets covered in soft sand) is built within a circlet of rocks, so the process of digging out can't attract a worm.

Comment: That's true, they do mostly anchor tents in rock somewhere.  However this is the passage that sparked the question.       "he (Leto, Chld-Dune) reached out (to) the sand-compaction tool. He gripped it, rolled onto his stomach, and breached the tent’s sphincter. A pool of sand drifted across his hand. , he worked swiftly, tunneling upward at a steep angle. Six times his body length he went before he broke out into darkness and clean air. He slipped out onto the moonlight windface of a long curving dune, found himself about a third of the way from the dune’s top.

Comment: @user5479 - That quote is referring to the first instance. Leto and his mother are using a tent in an area that is *"within [a] rock-enclosed hideaway"*. **They can make as much noise as they like because the worms can't get to them.**